# Running Yesod in Cloud9

Tags: haskell, yesod, cloud9-ide, haskell-stack

These are the steps I used to run a Yesod scaffold in Cloud9. The whole process took a few hours and I had to upgrade memory and disk (do this before proceeding):

### Installing Stack

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 575159689BEFB442`
2. (Ubuntu 14.04 (amd64)):
   `echo 'deb http://download.fpcomplete.com/ubuntu trusty main'|sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fpco.list`
3. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install stack -y`

*Status: running `$ stack` from the command line works as expected*

### Yesod Template Quickstart

1. Create a new scaffolded site: 
   `stack new yesodOnC9 yesod-postgres && cd yesodOnC9`
2. Install the yesod command line tool: 
   `stack build yesod-bin cabal-install --install-ghc`
3. Build libraries:
   `stack build`

### Create PostgreSQL Database in C9

1. Start the PostgreSQL service
    `$ sudo service postgresql start`
2. Connect to the service
    `$ sudo sudo -u postgres psql`
3. Create a PostgreSQL database (from inside psql, at last step)
    `postgres=# CREATE DATABASE "yesodDB";`
4. Create a test PostgreSQL database
    `postgres=# CREATE DATABASE "yesodDB_test"`
5. Set Password for Postgres User
    `postgres-# \password postgres`
    `Enter new password: MYPASSWORD`

*Result:*
  *user: postgres*
  *password: MYPASSWORD*

### Configure Yesod to Database

1. Open config/settings.yml
2. Change database user to:
     `user:     "_env:PGUSER:postgres"`
3. Change database password to:
     `password: "_env:PGPASS:MYPASSWORD"`
4. Change database database to:
     `database: "_env:PGDATABASE:yesodDB"`
5. Close settings.yml and open test-settings.yml
6. Change database database to:
    `database: yesodDB_test`

### Launch devel server:

1. `stack exec -- yesod devel -b $IP -p $PORT`

*Result: Successful, Running Scaffold*

> If you leave your workspace, you will have to restart the PostgreSQL service with: `$ sudo service postgresql start` when you return.

Comment: A script for setting up a database - https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/master/setup.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you configure Postgres to accept TCP connections as indicated by the error message? Your installation of Yesod seems ok, but Yesod reads the DB to make a migration at start time so it needs a connection to your DB.

Comment: If I don't make mistake, you don't have to install haskell-platform as stack take care of that.

Comment: To clarify, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install stack -y` would install haskell? So someone could skip directly to *Installing Stack*?

Comment: yes, you can read about it at [stack](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) page.

Comment: In fact "stack" is a binary that will install haskell.